# using klmr box::use in an rmarkdown document

Tags: r, r-box

Can anyone give me an example to add libraries and local functions with the [klmr::box](https://github.com/klmr/box) package in a rmarkdown document?

I am aware of their use in Rhino´s framework, but I feel a bit confused where can I declare modules and libraries in a YAML + Rmarkdown file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way is to remember he location of the .Rmd file.
The difference with the package `here::here` is that it does not go backwards from the .Rmd location. box yes, using `..` in fromt of module's statements.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE, warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
box::use(
  r/core[...],
  dplyr[
    `%>%`, mutate, across, rename, case_when, if_else,
    select, filter, group_by, left_join, summarise, pull, arrange, desc,
    n, n_distinct
  ],
  tidyr[pivot_wider, fill, complete, nesting, replace_na],
  glue[glue],
)

box::use(../data/constants)
box::use(../logic/some_function_in_project)
box::use(../logic/dependencies)

# example of alias
kable_formating <- dependencies$kable_formating$kable_formating
```
````

In their invocation, keep one eye in the relative locations:

- input, output: not passed to the internal .Rmd. So they begin from the current working enviroment where render is executed.
- lib, math, css: are relative to the final output file location.
- the knit_root_dir param can change the working directory where render and knit is executed. Keep it in mind this possibility if your .Rmd calls from inside modules to readjust their locations.

  ```r
  rmarkdown::render(
    input = 'doc/document.Rmd',
    output_format = 'prettydoc::html_pretty',
    output_file = output_filename,
    output_dir = output_dir,
    output_options = list(
      self_contained = TRUE,
      math = NULL,
      # lib_dir must be relative to the .Rmd
      # el .Rmd is in doc/
      # so go back to the doc's root with ".."
      # and go up with /reports/site_libs
      lib_dir = "../reports/site_libs",
      # css is relative to the output directory
      # aquí conviene duplicar la css en la carpeta output
      # for some reason, file.path does not work with css parameter
      css = paste("www", "style.css", sep = "/")
    ),
    params = list(
      id_prospect = id_prospect,
      dsn = dsn,
      pwd = pwd
    )
  )
  ```